# Pass mongodb data between java and nodejs

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, dashboard

The thing is i need to pass data(stored in mongodb) from my java application to my dashboard written in ExpressJS. whats the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the driver API for Java recommended on the MongoDB site?

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/

Comment: Yes im using it + morphia to make my life easier when it comes to mapping objects, the only thing is how to pass that data to my expressJS app in a efective way

Answer (score 0):

If the data has to come through your application, you can expose a REST API from your Java application and hit the API from your Express app.
 You can do it using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package.

If the Java application need not be included between MongoDB and Express, you can access the data straight from Express using [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) package.